# Getting error during upload of image in nodejs with multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer, body-parser

```js
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import ejs from "ejs";
import multer from "multer";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

// Image Upload

// Configure Multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./uploads");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now + "_" + file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
});

// Connect to MongoDB database

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/restaurantDB")
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database Created Succesfuly");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        comsole.log(err);
    });

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imagePath: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs");
});
app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.render("about.ejs");
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
    res.render("contact.ejs");
});
app.get("/pizza", (req, res) => {
    res.render("pizza.ejs");
});
app.get("/burgur", (req, res) => {
    res.render("burgur.ejs");
});
app.get("/beverage", (req, res) => {
    res.render("beverage.ejs");
});
app.get("/addproduct", (req, res) => {
    res.render("addproduct.ejs");
});

app.get("/product", (req, res) => {
    res.render("product.ejs");
});

app.post("/addproduct", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body["id"];
    const name = req.body["name"];
    const description = req.body["description"];
    const price = req.body["price"];
    const type = req.body["type"];
    const file = req.file;

    if (!file) {
        // Handle the file upload error
        return res.status(400).send("File upload failed");
    }

    const product = new Product({
        _id: id,
        name: name,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        type: type,
        imagePath: `/uploads/${file.originalname}`
    });

    product.save();
    res.redirect("/product")

});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is my code and geting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'image')
> Please correct this code and explain me why is this happening

Comment: How are you sending the image, is it via a form or postman? If it's via a form please post the code from your `addproduct.ejs` so that we can help you debug. There could a number of reasons why you are getting the undefined TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

So when you say `upload.single("image")`, it tries to read file from `req.file.image`, your error says that req.file is undefined, so check how you are sending the file, mostly that is the error.

Request doesnot have file attach or make sure the name attribute of the file is "image" in your request.